# Visual Studio 2015 for Cordova - Can't build for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have successfully built my project for Android but during building for iOS I get an error:

> The remote build server denied the build request, because the client
>   certificate is invalid or has expired. To build your project, you must
>   generate and configure a security PIN. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=511904

I have generated a new pin (after doing a resetServerCert, followed by a generateClientCert), as described in the link above, I reinstalled the remotebuild tool, but all to no avail. It also doesn't matter if I just try to build or build/deploy to a local device.

I also tried building without pin, but that doesn't work either:

> Cannot POST
>   /build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=5.1.1&cfg=debug&options=--device

I am close to releasing my app, but the issues above have set me back a couple of days.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please make a backup of the your Project before trying anything - in my case it was a good advice:)! Did you try the command "remotebuild test --server --secure false http ://localhost:3000" on the mac in a second terminal window? Be sure to set the same options and port. If this gives a success, then try to clean the cordova cache in Visual Studio Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Button "Clear Cordova Cache". You have to reopen the solution. Another test: Did the remotebuild run's on a clean "Hello World" cordova project from Visual Studio? Wish you all the best for your going live!!

Comment: The "remotebuild test" in a second terminal runs successfully. I have tried that a couple of times tonight.

I also did a clean cordova cache, to no avail.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Bjoerg

I noticed a difference in the POST that comes from the 2nd terminal window (POST /cordova/build/tasks/?vcordova....) and the POST coming from Visual Studio (POST //build/tasks?command=build&vcordova....).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my first successful build after going through this page: [https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-ios.md](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-ios.md)

The issue was that I first had vs-mda-remote installed and then changed to remotebuild. You have to follow these steps in this situation:

1. generate and use a new PIN
2. If you are not using secure mode, turn secure mode on
3. Turn secure mode off again to cause VS to reinitalize

Answer (score 0):

From your comment that VS is trying to POST //build/tasks?command=build&vcordova it looks like it isn't configured properly: That empty URL segment should be "cordova", and that is discovered when you configure VS to talk to the remote agent in tools -> options.

If you go to Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Remote Agent Configuration and reconfigure your settings (Either disabling secure mode on the mac server, or generating a new pin to use) then VS should be able to connect.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I answered my question myself. I have changed the Remote Agent Configuration many times and that didn't solve the issue.